# Issue "Enabling simplink on boot automatically"

Tags: raspbian, cec-client

I need enable simplink on boot automatically. But, currently we have to do it manually every-time from Remote Control using the Settings->Input->Simplink->HDD Recorder.

I have been stuck for almost a week trying to figure out what the issue is. We are using a cec-client to control the LG TV. Is there a way to enable simplink on the TV from the Pi or any methods to enable simplink from the Pi side.

Hardware Used:

- Raspberry PI
- LG Television ( 32LF565B )

Any input is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Running the following commands in /etc/rc.local or in /etc/init.d/ will enable SIMPLINK on boot.

sudo cec-client &
sleep 20
sudo echo tx 2 82 00 | cec-client &